# What is the difference between a ported and non-ported licenses?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons, law

**What I know:**

From what I have read ported licenses are for specific locations while non-ported licenses have been customized to work in as many places as possible.

**Question:**

Even though I license my work under a ported license does that mean it won't work in other locations EVER or does it just mean that depending on the locations laws it may not fully be compatible?

Comment: Does this apply only to CC, or are there other licenses with this distinction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous versions, the Creative Commons licenses have been written with the US legal system in mind. This might have created some issues in other countries, so it was an effort underway to adapt the text to different countries and also to translate it in the process. You can look in this [Wikipedia-article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_jurisdiction_ports) or in the [FAQ of Creative Commons](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#What_should_I_know_about_differences_between_the_international_licenses_and_the_ported_licenses.3F) for more details.